# CSS: Make img fit completely in div

Tags: html, css, image, width

Working on a news site and once I get to mobile, I'd like it where the image fits inside the entire width of the div....whatever that might be. The images are originally 240px in width so we are talking about bumping them up. This is what I'm currently using:

```
.thumb { float: left; clear: both; width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0; }
.thumb img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
```

So on my iPhone, the pic it a little bit too small since the div is 320px and the img is 240. Of course, this would change for say, landscape at 480px for example. So it needs to be flexible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you set `width:100%;` for `.thumb img` rather than `max-width:100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the following, set the image width to 100%.

```css
.thumb {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
.thumb img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) //place whatever the resolution you are working here{
  /*enter your code here for this resolution*/
}
```

to learn more about
[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple as like this.

```css
img {
    width:100%;
}
div{
    float: left; clear: both; width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/conquer/assets/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg" />
</div>
```